# How common is fresh produce in the world of Firefly?

Tags: firefly, food, serenity

In the pilot of *Firefly*, Book uses fresh strawberries as part of his transport payment.

The "Mighty fine shindig" has unadorned fresh fruit, showing that it was considered fancy by itself, though Persephone wasn't the most civilized of worlds.

A guilt-ridden Jayne would later go on to buy apples for the crew, which was portrayed as very generous.

This shows that fresh produce is rare and expensive in the world of *Firefly*, at least to non-Core citizens.

Is it ever shown exactly how rare it is, or whether or not they're also rare in the Core?

Comment: Fresh strawberr*ies*? Seemed like it was only one.

Comment: Exotic fruit seems rare. Potatoes and suchlike are presumably quite common

Comment: @Randal'Thor He had a small box of them.

Comment: @RogueJedi If you watch the scene where Kaylee takes a strawberry out of the small box and eats it, it looks as though the strawberry is about the size of the box, meaning there was only one in there.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7idn3PcKBM

Comment: @RogueJedi Check out this thread at fireflyfans.net which asks the same question: http://www.fireflyfans.net/mthread.aspx?tid=6482

Comment: @Randal'Thor if you look at the meal scene later in the episode you do see them eating more strawberries and he is also helping with the meal prep.